# Counterexample for $\left | f \right |\in\mathcal{R}([a,b])\implies f\in \mathcal{R}([a,b])$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, examples-counterexamples

Someone can help me to find a counterexemple that the following proposition is not true:

$$\left | f \right |\in \mathcal{R}([a,b])\implies f\in \mathcal{R}([a,b])$$

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Do you mean riemann integrable? If so, take a function that is 1 on rationals and -1 on irrationals

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\ 
-1 & x\notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{matrix}\right.$

Can you see why it works?

Comment: It is not so clear can you explain it to me? Thank you a lot

Comment: Check out the definition of the Riemann integral (the one with partitions). Every interval contains a rational point and an irrational point. For a more detailed explanation, please write down your definion of the Riemann integral

Comment: $$f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$I_{k}=[x_{k-1},x_{k}]
L_{k}=inf[f(x)]
l_{k}=sup[f(x)]
s_{k}=l_{k}\Delta x_{k}
S_{k}=L_{k}\Delta x_{k}$$                                                                                                                                                   $$S=\sum S_{k} 
s=\sum s_{k} $$

$$sup s=\int_{\smile a}^{b}f(x) dx                                                                   
inf S=\int_{a}^{b\frown }f(x) dx$$                           

f is  integrable riemann if
$$\int_{\smile a}^{b}f(x) dx=
\int_{a}^{b\frown }f(x) dx$$